# Is there a way to select rows from an R script by condition?

Tags: r, selection

The question does not relate to selecting the rows of a data frame or a generic R object, but instead as stated, relates to selecting rows of a script.
E.g. How can I select all the odd rows from an R script?

Comment: This would depend on the IDE/text editor used more than on R.

Comment: You could read the script as text  into a data.frame or character vector and than select every second row/element. But that's... well... don't know why someone should do or need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### R

```r
txt <- readLines("path/to/script.R")
writeLines(txt[seq_along(txt) %% 2 == 0], "path/to/script_evenlines.R")
writeLines(txt[seq_along(txt) %% 2 == 1], "path/to/script_oddlines.R")
```

### sed

(On a bash or similar shell prompt.)

```r
sed -ne '0-2p' path/to/script.R > path/to/script_evenlines.R
sed -ne '1~2p' path/to/script.R > path/to/script_oddlines.R
```

This can be extended to *saving* every `N`th row with

```r
sed -ne '0-Np' path/to/script.R
```

or *deleting* every `N`th row with

```r
sed -e '0-Nd' path/to/script.R
```